# Atmosphere without Jersey

Tags: jersey, atmosphere

I'm writing a web application and wanted to ask if it is possible to use Atmosphere Framework without using Jersey. Do equivalent annotations of e.g. `@Produces` exist in Atmosphere?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the @ManagedService annotation provided out of the box by the framework: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-Started-with-the-ManagedService-Annotation